# UIApplication.shared.open with completion handler Swift 4

Tags: xcode9, swift4, uiapplication

Looking to open a link via UIApplication.shared.open in Swift4, Xcode9, I'm trying to use a completion block as is standard now, the most common stackoverflow answer is:

```
       UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:],
       completionHandler: {
           (success) in
              print("returned")
       })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to return any value and your code should work as it is. You just need to check if the browser was launched or not as follow:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

UIApplication.shared.open(url) { success in
    if success {
        print("browser successfuly opened")
    }
}
```